# How to define maximum and minimum values to be stored in a column in sql

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am trying to limit the possible values to be stored in a column from 1 to 10. I don't want to store anything less than 1 and more than 10. I'm trying to do it in Android Studio with Sqlite database. Is there any shortest possible method to do so?

Comment: search on google check constraints on sql side it's one ways i think so

Answer (score 0):

In the `CREATE` statement of the table define a [`check constraint`](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) for the column:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(..., yourcolumn INTEGER CHECK(yourcolumn BETWEEN 1 AND 10), ...);
```